# How to get an Access Userform to update an existing record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get an access userform button to run an update query.
The parameters I have are:

```
     Invoice number (should update Current ICB.Invoice number)
        Material Code (should update Current ICB.Material Code)
        Amount USD (Should update current ICB.Amount USD)
        Username (Should update current ICB.Owner)
    Vendor Code (Should update current ICB.Vendor code)
Record Number (Should = current ICB.ID)
```

I want to use a button on the form to check for a record that has the same record number and update the fields listed above with the values entered into the userform. I would use an update query but writing SQL into VBA is not my strong point. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any code to post?  Plus you don't need to do it in VBA, you could have a query for it.

Comment: Try `Refresh`. If it doesn't help, try `Requery`.

Comment: Are you talking about a Access form, or a office "user" form that cannot be bound to a data source?

Answer (score 0):

In the OnClick event of the button, do something like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from MyTable where RecordNumber = " & ICB.ID & "")

rec.Edit
rec("InvoiceNumber") = ICB.Invoice_number
rec("MaterialCode") = ICB.Material_Code
etc...
rec.update

rec.close
```

Use your actual table and field names, but that's the general idea.

If you absolutely insist on using a query, then you need to write the SQL in code in a similar way and use DoCmd.RunSQL.  Something like this:

```
txtSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET InvoiceNumber = " & ICB.Invoice_number & ", " & _
           " MaterialCode = " & ICB.Material_Code & "" & _
           etc...
           " WHERE RecordNumber = " & ICB.ID & ""
DoCmd.RunSQL txtSQL
```

This assumes you're only using integers.  If you're storing the data as text, it needs to be surrounded by single quotes.

```
   " MaterialCode = '" & ICB.Material_Code & "'" & _
```